# what is the difference between the two regex(negative lookaround)?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

i could match content between tr tags with this regex:

`<tr\s+class='test'>((?!</tr>).)*</tr>`

but if i put the star quantifiers inside the parenthesis right next to the dot metacharacters,they match only the whole pattern with capturing group empty.

```
$string = "<tr class='test'>
<td>test1</td>
</tr>
 <div class='ignored' >text text</div>
 <tr class='test'>
 <td>test2</td>
 </tr>";


preg_match_all("|<tr\s+class='test'>((?!</tr>).*)</tr>|si",$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

i know what lookaround is but i'm not quite sure what exactly cause the difference. hope someone can shed some light on this. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, parsing HTML with regex? It's been some time since I saw a question in that aspect :-) Hopefully you are aware of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Good luck by the way with finding the *right expression*.

Comment: Thanks for the link. i tried simple_html_dom but was unable to use it solve my problem. what alternatives do you recommend if i want to extract contents from tr tags with a certian class name? Anyway, i'm learning regex and want to understand how it works.

Comment: Sorry I am not a PHP developer and cannot offer good frameworks for HTML parsing. What I can say for sure is that if you want to learn regex, parsing HTML is the WORST possible example you might pick to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((?!</tr>).)*
```

The repetition is applied to `((?!</tr>).)` and there is a single `.` and a single lookahead. Therefore, this will check each and every `.` (at each repetition) and make sure they are not followed by `</tr>`.

```
((?!</tr>).*)
```

This is actually `(?!</tr>).*` in disguise. There is a single lookahead and a single `.*`. The lookahead will check only the first `.`, but not the others, which is why everything will be matched, unless the immediate dots after the lookahead matches `</tr>`.